# Changing scenes in Godot

Tags: game-development, 2d-games, godot

I'm new to Godot and I'm working on a personal project. I have to make my character move from one scene to another. The way I did it was to make an Area2D add a collision shape, and then connect it with the player so if the player enters that Area2D it is sent to the other scene. It works perfectly, but the problem is I can't go back.

I used `get_tree().change_scene("")` to change the scene once the Area2D is entered by the player, but when I do it on the other scene it doesn't work.

Why???

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that there is some other manipulation of the scene tree that is messing it up. Is current_scene valid after the change? I had similar problems with some setup hard to explain on a comment, suffice to say it involved manipulating current_scene by other means. At the end I decided to not use change_scene but instead have a relatively empty base scene where I instance the other scenes inside, it is more work, but gives you much more control.

Comment: Try different then, because is difficult to explain, open the game on the 2nd scene and see if the area2D + Collision shape are doing the same work at it is on the first scene. Maybe you forgot to include the script, or maybe you forgot to include the signal correctly on the second Scene.